# Reducing a Swift array to [Int:Int?] with nil initializer is empty

Tags: arrays, swift, reduce

Why does reducing an array into a hash with the keys as array values and the value as nil give an empty result?

```swift
[1,2,3].reduce(into: [Int:Int?](), { $0[$1] = nil })
[1,2,3].reduce(into: [Int:Int?](), { $0[$1] = 1 })
```

Both of these should have 3 entries, right?

Comment: seting a dictionary value to nil is the same as removing it. So you actually never set any value to those keys

Comment: Ugh you're right! A work around for this is to store your keys separately like `Set<K>, Dictionary<K,V>` then treat anything missing from the Dictionary as nil

Comment: @ElectricPenguin That's not at all necessary. See my answer (will be up in a minute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift, setting a dictionary value to `nil` like you did in the question removes that value from the dictionary entirely. However there are some odd caveats to this.

In your example, you use a `Dictionary` with type `[Int:Int?]`:

```
var dictionary: [Int:Int?] = [1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1]
```

Setting a value to `nil` in the following way removes it:

```
dictionary[1] = nil
```

Setting a value to `nil` with type `Int?` will assign `nil` instead:

```
dictionary[1] = nil as Int?
```

Likewise, using the `updateValue(_:forKey:)` function will do the same:

```
dictionary.updateValue(nil, forKey: 1)
```

Printing the dictionary after performing either of these operations would show the following:

```
[1: nil, 2: Optional(1), 3: Optional(1)]
```

So the behavior is a bit odd but it is possible to achieve your intended result. I don't really recommend it because of how unnatural it is; it is possible, though.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is not at all odd actually, and it's a really natural outcome if you understand some fundamental features of Swift's dictionaries and optionals.

#### Nested optionals

Firstly, optionals are composable. You can have nested optionals, like `Optional<Optional<Int>>` (a.k.a. `Int??)`. A nested optional like this has possible three values. To illustrate their difference, imagine the result of `array.first`, where `array` has type `Array<Optional<Optional<Int>>`:

1. `Optional.some(Optional.some(someWrappedValue))`, which is just the "non-nil" case, with a payload of `someWrappedValue`. In the context of `array.first`, that means the array is non-empty, and the first element is non-nil value `someWrappedValue` (of type `Int`).
2. `Optional.some(Optional.none)`, which is a non-nil optional containing a `nil`. In the context of `array.first`, that means ten array is non-empty, and the first element is itself `nil`.
3. `Optional.none`, which is just a `nil` optional. In the context of `array.first`, that means the array is empty, and there is no first element.

Note the different between case 2 and case 3. "Where" the nil is "found" along the chain has a semantic difference. `Optional.none` (a.k.a. nil) means there are no elements, which is semantically different to `Optional.some(Optional.none)`, which means there *are* elements, but the first of them is actually `nil`.

#### The precise meaning of `nil`

Secondly, `nil` is a shorthand for `Optional<T>.none`, where `T` is inferred from the context. For example, that's why `let x = nil` is illegal, because the type inference system has no clues as to what value of `T` is appropriate.

Note that `nil` on its own is inferred to a `none` at the "earliest" ("outermost") level of optionality. (Case 3, in the list above)

#### Assign nil through a dictionary subscript

Thirdly, assigning `nil` to a Dictionary through a subscript erases the value for the given key.

#### Putting it together

Given these three points, we can consider your example. The subscript of a dictionary is "one layer more optional" than the `Value` generic type of the dictionary. E.g. for a dict of type `[Int: Int]`, the return type of the subscript operator is `V?`, and correspondingly, you can assign `Int?`.

Now consider your dictionary, of type `[Int: Int?]`. The subscript takes/returns an `Int??`. Let's consider the three possible cases in context, as before:

1. Assigning a value of type `Optional.some(Optional.some(someWrappedValue))` makes the dict store a value of `someWrappedValue` for the key, as an `Int?`. This is what's happening when you write `$0[$1] = 1` (Swift is implicitly promoting `1` to `Optional.some(Optional.some(1))`.
2. Assigning a value of type `Optional.some(Optional.none)` makes the dict store a value of `nil` for the key, as an `Int?`. This is the part you were missing.
3. Assigning a value of type `Optional.none` makes the dict erase any value that might have existed for the key. This is what's happening when you write `$0[$1] = nil`

So to make this code give your designed outcome, you need to supply a value of the second type. You can do this with:

```
[1,2,3].reduce(into: [Int:Int?]()) { $0[$1] = Optional.some(nil) }
```